# Python 2.7 can't find vcvarsall.bat, MS VS C++ 2008 is installed

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

So I've been working with python 2.7 no problem for a while now. I've been using pip for a couple of months without issue. I recently installed virtualenv and now none of my pythons or pip can find vcvarsall.bat, even though this wasn't a problem before. I thought virtualenv seemed like a good idea, but not if it breaks everything around it. I tried to run repair on VS C++ but it didn't find any problems. Has anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat help?

Comment: I saw that answer on my initial run through, but it didn't seem to be the same problem. If this worked before and doesn't now, and I have C++ 2008 installed, why would I suddenly need to change my environmental variables to point to the wrong version?

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the problem is that Python 2.7 64 bit has a compilation problem. It would seem that I need to download a special package from MS to get access to 64-bit c/c++ compiler that's compatible with Python 2.7. Not a problem, except that's its 3 gigabytes. So, I just did it on my Linux VM and Windows Python 2.7 is 32-bit for me now. Not the best solution, but we're supposedly going to upgrade to Python 3 one of these years. Probably about when Python 4 comes out and the Python 3 compiler is obsolete too. C'est le vie!